# JavaFX - Constraints in programmatically scrolling a ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to scroll a `ScrollPane` that contains an XYChart via code.

```
@FXML
private ScrollPane graphSP;
```

Scrolling it, for instance, to the `half-way point` works with this sequence:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.show();
graphSP.setHvalue(.5);
```

The problem is, if I place that call to `setHvalue()` elsewhere, it just does nothing.

So wondering, what are the constraints to actually cause the `ScrollPane` to scroll? Or, where can I call `setHvalue()` in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Hvalue/Vvalue of the ScrollPane after the scene is visible i.e. `stage.isShowing()` is true.

**EDIT**

One way to call it is after the `stage.show()` is called.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(chart);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
        scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5);
        scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But, there may be cases where a reference to stage is not available. In those case you can use the following :

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(new NumberAxis(), new NumberAxis());
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(chart);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane, 300, 300));

        scrollPane.getScene().getWindow().showingProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                scrollPane.setVvalue(0.5);
                scrollPane.setHvalue(0.5);
            }
        });
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's the answer. I tried in the debugger, setting foo = graphSP.isShowing() before the call to setHValue(). It's true in the instance where it works. And true in the instance where it fails. I tried adding this code so the whole thing happens based on a listener: `graphSP.visibleProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observableValue, final Boolean aBoolean, final Boolean aBoolean2) {
            System.out.println("debug: changed");
        }` <--- the println was never called.

Comment: I didn't ask you to add manipulate with `isShowing()` property. Always set the value after stage is visible. The reason why I said to check it is because all the height and width are manipulated on the `stage.show()`.

Comment: Well my listener idea was to try to make sure I got called to do the scrolling at the right point. But at least the way I have it, it's not being called. Any idea how to actually implement updating the scroll position at the right time (when the stage is visible as you say?

Comment: When do you want to call it?

Comment: I want to call it whenever it will actually work. The listener I tried (above) is never called, so it would have to be some other way.

Comment: Thanks very much for examples. But, trying the addListener approach and did the following: I added `System.out.println("I got called");` just before `if (newValue)`. I only ever saw that print when I closed the stage window, like after it had closed. Not on opening of window, not on resize, not on scrolling the scrollers, etc. Never called except after closing the window.

Comment: It will be called when `primaryStage.show();` is called.